# Cannot get mount command in Terminal

Tags: partitioning, mount, gnome-terminal

I tried using mount command in Terminal  and it did not provide any information, only:-

```
<david@david-Original ~>$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1539644k,nr_inodes=211868,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=310112k,mode=755)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.perf_event)
19:33:29
ory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=36,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime)
cgmfs on /run/cgmanager/fs type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=100k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=310112k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/david/My Passport type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb6 on /media/david/a8113041-28ca-4898-b36f-33c9c0f492f4 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)

<david@david-Original ~>$
```

****** what am I doing wrong  I have at least one hard disk and one usb external disk

Comment: What kind of information do you want?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong. The command shows all mounted devices.

`/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` is mounted in `/`, your root filesystem and `/dev/sda1` is mounted in `/boot` via the configuration in your `/etc/fstab`.

And there is one external drive, with the partitions `sdb1` and `sdb6`, mounted in `/media/david`. One per UUID `a8113041-28ca-4898-b36f-33c9c0f492f4` and one by partition name or device name `My Passport` via `udev` rules.

Comment: Thanks I am a new user and could not see the wood from the trees

Comment: You could accept the answer. Click the check mark at the left side of the answer. **;)**

Answer (score 0):

It's not broken, it's doing what it's supposed to.  If you're trying to mount something, you have to tell it what to mount and where.  Try `man mount` for more info.

`mount` on its own just tells you everything mounted and where it's mounted.  If you want some more useful info (I say more just because it's got sizes and such) try running `df -vh`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip it does provide clearer information I want to make sure I unmount and mount the right drives